# How to create multiple new records, checking for existing duplicates, and adding new or existing record to join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing a simple blogging app that creates posts and adds multiple tags to the post via

`has_many :tags, :through => :tag_joins`

Tags are pulled from a comma separated string typed into the view which is separated into individual tags by a regex in the post create action.

```
def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    @tags = @post.tagstring.split(/\s*,\s*/)
    @tags.each do |i|
      @tag = Tag.new(:name => i)
      if @tag.save
        @post.tags << @tag
      end
    end
    format.html { redirect_to "/#{@post.permalink}", notice: "success" }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
  end
end
end
```

This works fine except is creating duplicate tags in the tag table.

How would I check to see if a tag already exists and, if it does, add the existing one to the post rather than creating a new one? I have looked at using `first_or_create` but am having difficulty getting my head around how it would fit within the context of another create action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `first_or_initialize` will help you..

```
@tags.each do |i|
  tag = Tag.where(name: i).first_or_initialize
  if tag.persisted? || tag.save
    @post.tags << tag
  end
end
```

Check docs here [`persisted?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F)

If there's a possibility of deleting tags then, check `!tag.new_record?` instead.

Read [`new_record?`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/new_record%3F)

Comment: Worked well thanks. I didn't know about `persisted?`.. i have a bit of learning to do

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_or_initialize_by`. Something like this:

```
  @tag = Tag.find_or_initialize_by(:name => i)
```

Because, if the `@tag` already exists, you won't create a new one.

Then you probably want to do some check on that, like:

```
  if @tag.new_record? 
    @post.tags << @tag if @tag.save
  else
    @post.tags << @tag
  end
```

That `if` statement is sort of jenk. Sorry about that. If I were you, I'd spend a few minutes making it cooler.

Comment: This works well too, thanks. I went with the other answer as he helped me out with the cooler if statement though

Comment: Good call! His `if` statement is definitely better!